# How to initialize a table column after a certain migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework and ASP.Net, one of my entity models is:

```
public class Records {

    public bool IsPublic {get; set;}
    // Some other properties
}
```

I have changed the model to:

```
public class Records {

    [obsolete]
    public bool IsPublic {get; set;}

    public RecordAccess AccessLevel {get; set;}
}
```

Where

```
public enum RecordAccess {Public, Private, Group };
```

After this migration, I need to initialize the new column (AccessLevel) *based on `IsPublic` column and some other tables*.

So I wrote the c# code to initialize the `AccessLevel` and put it in the `Seed` method.

**Note**

- I want to delete `IsPublic` column since it's no longer being used.
- I have 4 different databases which I'm working on: localdb, test server, staging server and production server. These databases might not be in the same state. So data and the table schemas might be different.

**Question**

- Is `Seed` method the right place to put the initialization?
  (If I delete the `IsPublic` from the `Record` class the code won't be compiled)
- How can I roll back the migration and data to what it was before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the initialization in the migration itself using the Sql("[INSERT SQL HERE]") method.  This is assuming that this is a one time move.

If you put it in the Seed method, the code will run every time the database is updated with new migrations, which means that you will probably end up writing code that checks to see if this has already been done and ignoring it, making it one time use, which basically makes it a migration.

To rollback your database, in the Package Manager Console window, use the Update-Database -TargetMigration [name of last good migration]. More Info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#specific).